# Unifi Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-18.04, unifi

Is there a way to put the following ports behind a reverse proxy using apache 2?

- UDP  3478    Port used for STUN.
- TCP  8080    Port used for device and controller communication.
- TCP  8443    Port used for controller GUI/API as seen in a web browser
- TCP  8880    Port used for HTTP portal redirection.
- TCP  8843    Port used for HTTPS portal redirection.
- TCP  6789    Port used for UniFi mobile speed test.

I can successfully get 8443 to work fine, but if I try to proxy any of the other ports my devices lose communication through my proxy, I've tried using WS and WSS? Any help would be appreciated! I seen that someone was able to do this with NGINX but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Apache2 or nginx are HTTP reverse proxies, meaning that they won't be able to pass a request to a device/app not supporting HTTP.

Comment: Someone here https://community.ui.com/questions/All-unifi-controller-ports-behind-reverse-proxy/fc52545a-6dbe-4ded-9ad4-de0ac4e68491 was able to do it using NGINX I guess I might just have to look into going that path.